# How to get the next blob in Python Google Cloud Storage library method list_blobs

Tags: python, google-cloud-storage

It seems to me that `google.cloud.storage.Client::list_blobs` returns a `HTTPIterator` which is not a proper python iterator. See below:

```py
import google.cloud.storage as gcs

client = gcs.Client()

blobs = client.list_blobs("mybucket")
blob = next(blobs)  # TypeError: 'HTTPIterator' object is not an iterator

blob = blobs.__next__()  # AttributeError: 'HTTPIterator' object has no attribute '__next__'
```

I'm looking for a solution that does not iterate through the entire iterator. The only solution I can come up with is a silly hack: for loop and break after the first loop.

Comment: May be `iter(blobs).__next__()`? or `next(iter(blobs))`

Comment: Hi,  did you solve your error? I am facing same issue, can you help me out?

Answer (score 3):

Without understanding the details of a Page Iterator, you can simply convert the iterator to a list:

```
blobs = client.list_blobs(bucketName)
blob_list = list(blobs)

# First blob
blob_list[0].name

# Second blob
blob_list[1].name

# Of course you can check the number of list items with len()
count = len(blob_list)
```

In reality, it is important to understand that the function `list_blobs()` does not fetch everything all at once. Typically, the library will fetch 1,000 objects at a time. This is called paging. Assuming a bucket has 1,500 objects, two pages of objects will be fetched by iteration (1000 objects and 500 objects). However, less than 1,000 objects might be returned.

```
blobs = client.list_blobs(bucketName)
for page in blobs.pages:
        print('Page number: ', blobs.page_number)
        print('Count:       ', page.num_items)
```

Output:

```
Page number:  1
Count:        1000
Page number:  2
Count:        500
```

When you convert a Page Iterator to a list, all of the objects are fetched. For large buckets, this could take a substantial amount of time to only display the first and next objects.

For a better understanding, study the source code for the Page Iterator.

[Page Iterators](https://googleapis.dev/python/google-api-core/latest/page_iterator.html)

Comment: Your first solution does not satisfy a "a solution that does not iterate through the entire iterator". Casting to a list effectively does this as it needs to traverse through every element to create that list. You did however provide an idea, call `next(blobs.pages)` and take the first item in that page. However the iteration logic becomes difficult if you want to get the 2nd, 3rd, 4th, etc until (N-1)th where N is  the max number of blobs.

Comment: "In reality, it is important to understand that the function list_blobs() does not fetch everything all at once." Yep, and I do want this property. For example, let's say you want to "find the first N objects in the bucket without traversing the entire bucket".

Comment: @keto - In my second example, use the page iterator and iterate in pages. Once you read past what you want, break out. Otherwise, you cannot use the library as you want, so you will have to write your own code.